# TableSorter : Sorting Works Randomly on Columns

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I have table with collapsible rows. TableSorter is working fine for first column.

Expected Behaviour : It has to sort asc/desc on each column

But What is happening, click on first column (sorted) then click on third(sorted) again click on third column  ( no response) Again click on first column ( sorted)

There is no error in the console.

Here is [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o1zmkdch/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#tb").tablesorter();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

upgraded bootstrad
and table sorter added theme css
work for me
[here](http://%20https://jsfiddle.net/qozt4750/13/)

Comment: Checked issue is still the same.  click on name (double times) Sorting Worked well. Now sort Market Price Asc order, now clicking again on Market Price, no change in the columns